# Check user logged in to SharePoint Online from ASP.NET

Tags: sharepoint

How to check if user has logged in to `SharePoint Online` or not from a web application?

An approach is search for cookies of `SharePoint` in local machine, but it throw a security problem.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, exactly a trick that come from `jQuery.getScript()`

Using a function that return a string, and place one in web page, one in a `.js` file and upload to SPO doccument library. For example:

This function put in local web page:

```
function whereAmI(){
    return "local";
}
```

This function save in a `xxx.js` file and upload to SPO:

```
function whereAmI(){
    return "remote";
```

Notice those two function have same name.

Then in local web page, insert the following code:

```
jQuery.getScript("https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/DocLib/xxx.js", function () {
            if (whereAmI() == "local") // if not logged in, getScript failed to get xxx.js, so the page call local whereAmI
                // do something;
        });
```

That's it.